# What Causes Ubuntu 20.04 Server Edition to Automatically Suspend?

Tags: server, 20.04, suspend, power-management, acpi

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 Server Edition on an i7-5930K machine, I notice that the system will automatically be suspended after a short period of no user interaction.

The automatic suspend had to be disabled by running the command

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Why was the system automatically suspended? Shouldn't the suspend settings be disabled by default, especially since this is a server installation of Ubuntu? Is it because of a motherboard BIOS setting?

Comment: I have the same problem with the same Ubuntu server version. Problem occurred after upgrading from 18.04. I applied your solution. Let's see if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Mines still suspending every 20 mins.

Comment: I had similar issue after setting up vnc with genome, It's odd that default setting makes the machine suspend every 20 mins.  I turned it off via IMPI interface.

Answer (score 0):

check what autosuspend.service is doing:

```
$ sudo systemctl status autosuspend
```

and disable if needed by:

```
sudo systemctl stop autosuspend
sudo systemctl disable autosuspend
```